# How to change all hihats to ride cymbal in GuitarPro

Tags: notation, drums, guitar-pro

I'm not sure if this qn belongs here, but it is related to music, so here it goes.

I've been modifying some drum tabs on Guitar Pro. The problem is, for a specific section all the HiHat notes need to be changed to Ride cymbal.

Now of course, I can do it one note at a time. I can select the note, remove the hihat and add a ride cymbal on the same note. But I'll have to do this for one at a time for a loooong time.

Is there a mass copy and replace method in guitar pro.

Again, I can copy and paste notes too, but on the same note there'll be different snare/kick being played.

> I JUST want to replace the hihat with ride while keeping other things
>   same for the same note

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any 'find and replace' method in GP. You might have to  do it on every single note

Comment: http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, I just figured out how and also tested it.

1. Export the current GP file as an XML file from: File > Export > MusicXML,
2. Open the exported XML file with Notepad and using "replace all" (using ctrl + H) replace the number corresponding to HiHat (probably 42, 44 or 46) with a number corresponding to Ride cymbal (probably 59).
3. Import this file into GuitarPro  from: File > Import > MusicXML and you're done.

Hopefully nothing else will change. If it does,then you'll have to investigate the XML file more thoroughly but I don't think it's gonna be too hard. Anyway, keep the backup file safe before doing this, good luck.

Comment: this is why i love stack exchange! thank you for the answer. I'll try it out and let you know!

Comment: Great, and since you're trying it, it's better to consider @david strachan's advice and search for <fret>42</fret> (or 44, or 46, whichever you want to change) instead of just number 42 and replace it with <fret>51</fret> (or 59) just to be sure that nothing else will be changed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy drum track to new file as precussion track
2. Export as MusicXML

[image]

3. Open file in Text Editor
4. Look for `<fret>42</fret>` OR `<fret>44</fret>` OR `<fret>46</fret>`
5. Find and Replace with `<fret>51</fret>` OR  `<fret>59</fret>`
6. Import as MusicXML into drum file
7. Add track to origonal file